# Allow us to request improvements on a topic for which we have a proposed change

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Currently, if I've made a proposed change to a topic, there's not much I can do with it until the change is approved or rejected.

For instance, I'm trying to clean up the Introduction to DOM topic to remove examples which belong in a separate topic. I've made [a proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/80199) for moving the Tree Walker example into a new topic.

While I wait for that to go through, I wanted to add improvement requests to the other examples, so that:

1. Other people can pitch in and help move other examples.
2. Warn people that these examples are being moved, so suggesting changes to them is counterproductive.

However, when I go to [the topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom/2584/introduction-to-dom#t=20160808192542752166) I see a banner:

> [image: Banner indicating some other version is present]

And I don't see the flag icon for the topic, or any of its examples.

This behavior makes it more difficult to improve topics collaboratively, as I'm more likely to batch my edits into one large one in order to ensure all of the desired changes are complete.

My feature request is to **allow us to continue to make improvement requests, even if a proposed change is pending**.

This new behavior would allow more collaborative improvement by allowing editors to be requesting improvement even as they help.

*Note that this request is similar in content to [the bug report "Improvement request and proposed change are open the same link"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328922/improvement-request-and-proposed-change-are-open-the-same-link), but mine is a feature request, as I don't know that it's really a bug per se.*

Comment: omg yes please. I just fixed up some minor things in a topic and found a big factual inaccuracy in the topic, but don't have the time (or energy) to fix it myself. But I will definitely not retract my (rather substantial) edit, just to be able to request an improvement